# positioning pop-up iframe according scrollTop of top window

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I'm developing plugin which has some pop-up. Plugin is included on some page like iframe but with different domain. There is not allowed to do any other changes on that page except to add this iframe.

```html
<iframe class="frame" style="width:100%" src="another-domain.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="4500px"></iframe>
```

Pay attention that scrolling="no" and height is much bigger then heigh of page.
Pop-up should be vertically centered on the page when it appears, doesn't matter how much user scrolled down the page. See the pic

[image]

I tried $(top.window).scrollTop() but there is Cross-domain problem.

Is there any css trick to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is completely confusing. Is popup in iframe or is iframe in popup? What needs centering where? Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `transform: translate()` function CSS

```css
iframe {
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
```

```html
<iframe class="frame" style="width:100%" src="another-domain.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="4500px"></iframe>
```

Comment: it's not point to centralize iframe, I need to centralize pop-up which is div in iframe.

Comment: Ok, so share your popup! How do you think we can help you if you don't tell us the details? Please, share a working example. You can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask